# Default data in core data

Tags: ios, swift

Is there any way to set data into core data that will be there when a user installs an app?

Example:
I install my notes app. When I open it I already see a couple of notes that are read from core data(but I haven't created those notes, they came with the app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you add an attribute, open the data model inspector tab. Here you will get a field to set the default value to an attribute. For Attribute of Binary Data  type, the default value field is not available. I think for rest all it should be available.